# jQuery Instagram Bootstrap3 Dynamic Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to pull in images from instagram and put them into a Bootstrap3 Carousel so that each carousel item contains is 2 rows of 6 images.

I can get everything loaded in just fine, I just can't wrap my head around the logic to get the items displayed in the carousel correctly.

```
 var userFeed = new Instafeed({
            get: 'user',
            userId: <?= $user_id ?>,
            accessToken: '<?= $access_token ?>',
            limit: <?= $num_to_display ?>,
            success: function(data) {
                $('.carousel').carousel({interval:3000});
                // I have tried using .each() too,
                // can't break it into chunks that well
                for ( var i = 0; i < $(data.data).size(); i++ ) {
                    $('.carousel-inner').append('<div class="item"></div>');
                    $('.item').append('<div class="col-sm-2 instagram-placeholder"><img src='+data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url+' class="img-responsive"></div>');
                }
                $('.carousel').carousel('next');
            }
        });
userFeed.run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution:

In the html where you have your carousel, give "carousel-inner" div the id that is your instafeed's target. Put nothing inside this element. Like this:

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner" id="myfeed">

    </div>
</div>
```

Then, in your instafeed, build the template by putting images between divs that have class "item", and give the first item class "active":

```
    var userFeed = new Instafeed({
    ...
    template: '<div class="item"><img src="{{image}}"/></div>',
    ...
    after:
    function(){
    $('#myfeed > div:nth-child(1)').addClass('active');
    }

});
```

And now you should have a working Instafeed carousel.